# Need help regarding 3D floor plan for an app

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2, indoor-positioning-system, 3d-mapping

I am working on an Indoor positioning app based on beacons. I want to create this app for a specific floor of our building. Is there any API or any other way to create 3D floor plan?

Answer (score 4):

Full disclaimer: I am working at Archilogic

You could try [Archilogic](http://spaces.archilogic.com) - if you already have a 2D floor plan it usually takes less than 24 hours to get a 3D model back. If you don't have a floor plan, you could use the web editor to create the 3D model yourself, too.

The model can then be exported to OBJ or FBX, but that requires a paid plan.